# Regex distinguishing between Windows and Linux end of line characters

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I'm trying to distinguish between Linux/Unix end of line character `\n` and the Windows end of line `\r\n`. I cannot seem to find a unique regex string that will distinguish between the two situations. My code is

```
import regex 

winpattern = regex.compile("[(?m)[\r][\n]$",regex.DEBUG|regex.MULTILINE)

linuxpattern = regex.compile("^*.[^\r][\n]$", regex.DEBUG)

for i, line in enumerate(open('file8.py')):
    for match in regex.finditer(linuxpattern, line):
        print 'Found on line %s: %s' % (i+1, match.groups())
```

The `winpattern` and `linuxpattern` match both Windows and Linux. I want `linuxpattern` to only match Linux EOL and `winpattern` to only match Windows EOL. Any suggestions?

Comment: `[(?m)[\r][\n]$` says to match any of the characters in the set `[?()m\r` then `\n`, then end of line.

Answer (score 3):

When opening a file as a text file Python by default uses Universal Newline Mode (see [PEP 278](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0278/)), which means it converts all three newline type `\r\n`, `\r` and `\n` to just `\n`. This means that your regex are irrelevant: you already lost the information about newline type when you read the files.

To disable newline conversion you should pass the `newline=''` parameter to [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) (use [`io.open`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/io.html#io.open) for python<3):

```
$ echo 'Hello
> World
> ' > test.unix
$ cp test.unix test.dos
$ unix2dos test.dos
unix2dos: converting file test.dos to DOS format...
$ python3
Python 3.5.3 (default, Nov 23 2017, 11:34:05) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170406] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> unix = open('test.unix', newline='').read()
>>> dos = open('test.dos', newline='').read()
>>> unix
'Hello\nWorld\n\n'
>>> dos
'Hello\r\nWorld\r\n\r\n'
```

Afterwards these regexes will work:

```
>>> import re
>>> winregex = re.compile(r'\r\n')
>>> unixregex = re.compile(r'[^\r]\n')
>>> winregex.findall(unix)
[]
>>> winregex.findall(dos)
['\r\n', '\r\n', '\r\n']
>>> unixregex.findall(unix)
['o\n', 'd\n']
>>> unixregex.findall(dos)
[]
```

Note that `$` matches right *before* the newline character when using `re.MULTILINE` and only the end of string without it. To correctly match any newline you should just remove the `$`.

If you want a regex that matches complete lines use something like this:

```
>>> unix_lines = re.compile(r'^(.*[^\r\n]\n|\n)', re.MULTILINE)
>>> dos_lines = re.compile(r'^.*\r\n', re.MULTILINE)
>>> unix_lines.findall(dos)
[]
>>> unix_lines.findall(unix)
['Hello\n', 'World\n', '\n']
>>> dos_lines.findall(unix)
[]
>>> dos_lines.findall(dos)
['Hello\r\n', 'World\r\n', '\r\n']
```